# Cannot log into my computer with my password

Tags: passwords, windows

could somebody please help me. I can't log into my computer with my password. I've restarting it, I've pushed shift and restart.then troubleshoot, then refresh pc. I don't have a recovery disk either, as when I purchased the computer, there were no disks that came with it. I have windows 8.1 I think. What can I do, as I have a lot of information on the computer, which I didn't get round to backing up on the flash drive yet. I might have been hacked.

Comment: Do you get an error message when trying to login, if so, what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to look at your "Sign-in Options" under the sign-in dialogue box. You may have switched from the "keypad" option to your email password "key" option (or vise versa).